# Taking a still photo RIGHT AFTER the session startRunning() produces very very dark photos

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, avfoundation, photo

A little of necessary background: 
I'm developing an app which utilizes a camera for tracking movement and if it is
found takes a photo. I'm tracking movement with opencv3. Since I'm analyzing the video stream
I have to start a photo session after the movement tracked. I shutdown down the movement tracking
video session and fire up a photo session.

The problem is as simple as this: taking a still photo RIGHT AFTER the `session.startRunning()`
produces several very very dark (nearly black) photos and only after that the photos are properly
exposed.

I prepared a very simple Xcode project with one view and one button which starts the session and
takes a photo. The app behaves exactly as I described.

It is here https://github.com/GrigoryPtashko/TakePhotoAfterSessionStart
The project is [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You can clone it and run on an iPhone to get a proof of what I'm talking about.

I initialize the camera in the `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```
    // fully initialize the front camera without starting the session
    var frontCamaDev: AVCaptureDevice!
    let availableCameraDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    for device in availableCameraDevices as! [AVCaptureDevice] {
        if device.position == .Front {
            frontCamaDev = device
        }
    }
    do {
        // connect input to session
        let frontCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamaDev)
        if session.canAddInput(frontCameraInput) {
            session.addInput(frontCameraInput)
        }

        // camera auth
        let authorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        switch authorizationStatus {
        case .NotDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo,
                completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) -> Void in
                    if granted {
                        NSLog("photo camera permission granted")
                    } else {
                        NSLog("photo camera permission denied. How are we gonna do our awesome photo sesh??!!")
                    }
            })
        case .Authorized:
            NSLog("photo camera authorized")
        case .Denied, .Restricted:
            NSLog("photo camera not authorized")
        }

        // connect output to session
        stillCamOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        if session.canAddOutput(stillCamOutput) {
            session.addOutput(stillCamOutput)
        }

        connection = stillCamOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        connection.videoOrientation =
            AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue)!

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    } catch {
        NSLog("error [\(error)]")
    }
```

And then in the button handler I start the session and take a picture:

```
    session.startRunning()

    stillCamOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(connection) {
        (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            NSLog("error while capturing still image: \(error)")

            return
        }

        if let image = UIImage(data:
            AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer))
        {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
            NSLog("photo taken!")
        }
    }
```

So, what I am talking about is the code after `session.startRunning()` that produces very dark photos.
Why is that?
I've checked the time for the session to start and it takes 130 - 150 ms. Which is pretty enough
time to initialize the camera in my opinion.

I've also tried to manually set the focus and exposure values but no luck.. It still produces dark
photos right after session start.

Any comments will be much, much appreciated..

Comment: Quite natural for auto-exposure to take few hundred millisec. The exact timing may strongly depend on the device. New 6s's are expected to have much better cameras, especially for darker lighting conditions. Which one did you test?

Comment: @AlexCohn, I tested it with 5s and 6. The results are the same. Two dark photos after the session starts and then properly exposed photos.
I also tested with manually setting the focus and exposure. But the result did not change.

Comment: @Grigory did you find a solution to this?